# Map Special Subjects to roles using WAS Scripting(Websphere)

Tags: automation, websphere, jython, administration

I am using the below script to map roles to special subjects:

```
       AdminApp.edit("EnterpriseApplicationName", '[-MapRolesToUsers [["Users" "AllAuthenticatedInTrustedRealms"]]]')
```

This one is not adding special subjects for the role "Users".I can still see the application has "None" in Special subjects for the enterprise application .

My requirement is once the application is installed,in the Security role to user/group mapping the role "users" should have the special subject "All Authenticated in Application's Realm"

Is there any other options to do it? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Have you called AdminConfig.save() after your script?

Comment: yes..i have used the save option. AdminApp.edit("OpsMRApp_V3.57_010919_test", '[-MapRolesToUsers [["Users" "AllAuthenticatedInApplicationsRealms"]]]')
AdminConfig.save()

Comment: @Gas Do you have any idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done a little bit differently. Check this page [Changing the user role mappings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEKCU_1.1.2.1/com.ibm.psc.doc/rs_original/installer/rs_t_change_user_role_map_cli.html). For special subject like Everyone or AllAuthenticated, command expects simple yes/no string.

```
AdminApp.edit(AppName, '[-MapRolesToUsers [[Role Everyone AllAuthenticated 
MappedUsers MappedGroups AllAuthenticatedInTrustedRealms MappedUsersAccessIDs 
MappedGroupsAccessIDs]]]')
AdminConfig.save()
```

So your command should be like this (and it works, I've tested it on my env):

```
AdminApp.edit('DefaultApplication', '[ -MapRolesToUsers [[ "Users" no yes "" "" no "" "" ]]]' )
```

which translates to:

- Everyone = no
- AllAuthenticated = yes
- "" - empty mapped users
- "" - empty mapped groups
- AllAuthenticatedInTrustedRealms  - no
- "" - empty MappedUsersAccessIDs
- "" - empty MappedGroupsAccessIDs

After AdminConig.save() and relogin in web admin console, I can see role correctly mapped to `All Authenticated in Application's Realm`.